# GLSL Orthogonal Projection

Tags: glsl

I've implemented some shaders for illumination using the eye direction(Phong, Blinn), I believe I am using a perspective projection in opengl, I am wondering what should I do to make the same shader working using an orthographic projection.
I haven't had the time to fully understand how the ortho projection works but I believe there is no camera so I don't understand if I still need to use the eye and how can I calculate it or I am simply wrong.

cheers.

Comment: Orthographic projection is pretty darned simple, lots of 2d or 3d tactical/strategy games use this type of view: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection

Comment: Technically there is never a camera. And switching from perspektive to ortho projection shouldn't have any influence on your shaders.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're doing lighting in post-projection space (which is unlikely), lighting works the same way regardless of projection.